# Using npm within a Play application

Tags: playframework, npm, sbt-web

From the [Play 2.3 Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration23#npm):

> npm can be used as well as WebJars by declaring a package.json file in the root of your project. Assets from npm packages are extracted into the same lib folder as WebJars so that, from a code perspective, there is no concern whether the asset is sourced from a WebJar or from an npm package.

I can't find anything else about using npm in the newer docs. From the mentioned dependency `com.typesafe.npm` I can only find versions compiled with Scala 2.10:

- [npm_2.10 1.0.0 in Bintray](https://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/npm_2.10/1.0.0/)
- [npm_2.10 1.1.1 in Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.typesafe%7Cnpm_2.10%7C1.1.1%7Cjar)

Both won't work with Play 2.5. Are there newer versions compiled with Scala 2.11 or is npm not used / supported any more.

Comment: `com.typesafe.npm` is a dependency of the sbt-js-engine plugin. Sbt and its plugins are compiled against Scala 2.10 only. Whatever version of Scala your app itself uses, sbt will use Scala 2.10. So `com.typesafe.npm` being available for 2.10 only isn't the issue.